# can I get the "date" of a photo with iPhoto on iOS?

Tags: ios, photos.app, metadata

I would like to know what date some of the photos on my iPhone were taken. Does iPhoto for iOS let me do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, iPhoto for iOS shows the date, time and if available address of the taken photo.